# How to alternate between constructors with different parameters in java?

Tags: java

I have a class with 2 constructors, one that takes a single object (fishes), and another that takes an array of objects called fishes (fishes). There is a function to add a fish to a basket:

```
public Basket(int weight, Fish fishes) {
    singleFish = true;
}

public Basket(int weight, Fish[] fishes) {
    singleFish = false;
}


public boolean addFishes(Fish fish) {
    //here I want to make it so that when I add a fish to a basket,
    //it no longer uses the top constructor.
}
```

Assuming that a basket starts with 1 fish, how can I make it so that it takes a fish and uses the second constructor after taking a fish?
Thank you very much.

Comment: when addFishes is called, you already have your basket. Why would you call any constructor at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Basket(int weight, Fish fish) {
    this(weight, new Fish[] {fish};
    singleFish = true;
}

public Basket(int weight, Fish[] fishes) {
    singleFish = fishes.length == 1;
}
```

Or here you need only a single constructor with a variadic parameter (`Fish...` is actual of type `Fish[]`):

```
private final Fish[] fishes;
private final boolean singleFish;

public Basket(int weight, Fish... fishes) {
    this.fishes = fishes;
    singleFish = fishes.length == 1;
}

new Basket(45, hering, sardine, riba);
new Basket(75, shark);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am not understanding the question correctly, why do you need to call the constructor twice? You could use something like this where your `Basket` maintains a list of fishes, creates it at instantiation and then adds fishes as desired. There is no need to maintain any information about how many fishes there are in the basket as you can infer this from the collection of fishes.

```
class Basket {
    Collection<Fish> fishes;

    public Basket(Fish... fishes) {
        this.fishes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fishes));
    }

    public void addFish(Fish... fishes) {
        this.fishes.addAll(Arrays.asList(fishes));
    }

    public boolean isSingleFish() {
        return this.fishes.size() == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<Fish> fishes;

public Basket(Fish fish) {
    this(Collections.singletonList(fish));
}

public Basket(List<Fish> fishes) {
    this.fishes = fishes == null ? new ArrayList<>() : fishes;
}

public isSingle() {
    return fish.size() == 1;
}

public boolean addFishes(Fish fish) {
    fishes.add(fish);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor to be used is selected based on the type of parameters you pass to it.

An array of `Fish` is a different type than `Fish` it self.
In Java, any array of any type is a type of its own.

So, all you have to do is pass an array of `Fish` objects.
This array can be empty, or it can have only one object, but it has to be an array:

```
Fish [] fishes = new Fish[0];

Basket b = new Basket(0, fishes);
```

In this example, do not pass a fish, but you do pass a valid array object.
It does not have space even for a single fish, but that does not matter.
It is still a valid object of type `Fish[]` so the second constructor will be called.

Note, that you can not pass `null` to `Basket` constructor, because the compiler will not know which constructor version to choose.